# How to Publish API

Tags: web-services, api, ionic2

I don't know if this is a good place to ask this question but I am new to the concept of API and I want to stop testing the API on my localhost and I was wondering how they can be published and how can I connect them to my DB servers any advice.

Comment: Can you tell more about your API?

Comment: well it is in php and I am using it to build a mobile application with ionic 2

Comment: What is the problem there? You can publish or host your API service and then you can use it with any front end app no? So then?

Comment: yeah that is my question what are these service is it okay if I use FTP server to upload them and use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to host your PHP API on either your own server or you can use Heroku.There is no limitation for you.Also, you can use Azure, AWS and etc.But with Ionic most popular one is Heroku.

You can see more about [**Heroku here**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#introduction)

Comment: so it is okay if upload on the same server that I upload my DB and does Heroku allow my to connect to remote DB ??

Comment: Yes, You can.After you'll create a free account you can get support from them too if you need additional help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help